# What should I name an enum describing whether a field is hidden, optional, or required?

Tags: c#, enums

I have a control with a bunch of fields that I want a user to be able to configure.

I originally had this:

```
    public bool Phone1Visible;
    public bool Phone1Required;
```

Then realized that I didn't want to deal with having to validate again hidden required fields, so I came up with this:

```
public enum YOUR_NAME_HERE
{
    Hidden,
    Optional,
    Required
}
```

What would you name this enum?  I was thinking "FieldCriticality", but that sounds a little wordy.

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `FieldValidation`, as a descriptive title of how you wish to use this enum.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `FieldState`.

Answer (score 2):

How about `FieldMode`? I think “mode” helps convey that this isn't to do with the *value* of the field, or how the user is currently interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would go by FieldType

```
public enum FieldType
{
    Hidden,
    Optional,
    Required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use FieldProperty or FieldAttribute

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `FieldModifier` or `FieldInteraction` would suit you?

Answer (score 0):

Status

As simple as it gets.

Then you'd get

```
public Status Phone1Visible;
public Status Phone1Required;
```

which seems very readable and explanatory, expeciaally when popping up with Intellisense

Comment: "Status" seems not quite descriptive enough.  Maybe "FieldStatus"?

Comment: Agreed. From my experience though, Field doesn't really make it much more descriptive. If you have additional types of statuses, I completely agree that FieldStatus is much more useful. But if you don't, I still feel that simpler is better. And with your variables, it's very readable. What's the Status of Phone1Visible vs What's the FieldStatus of Phone1Visible.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a while thinking about this problem and ended up with:

```
public enum ValidationMode
{
    Optional,
    Required
}
```

because in the end I would use this information for validation. I feel that the suggestions such as "FieldType" refers more to the fields internal type (text field, checkbox field).

Answer (score 0):

I often use `InputPolicy` for enums like this.